# Actionscript 3 interfacing - I'm not understanding it (beginner question)

Tags: actionscript-3, interface

From what I read, interfaces are basically classes for methods, right? If two classes implements the same interface, then they should both have methods described in the interface.

Now, how is this useful? Let's say I want to call foo();.

```
public interface IExample {
    function foo(om:String):void;
}

class HungryClass implements IExample{
    public function foo(om:String):void{
        trace("OM NOM NOM!!! Thank you for feeding me" + om);
    }
}

class FullClass implements IExample{
    public function foo(om:String):void{
        trace("No thanks, I don't want to eat" + om);
    }
}

//somewhere..
instanceOfEitherClass.foo("cake");
```

How does interfacing help? Wouldn't this work without interfacing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say you have a concrete class that inherits from an abstract class. In that case you would simply do the following:

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass
```

Now how about if you need the concrete class to also inherit from the `EventDispatcher` class? You can't do the following:

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass, EventDispatcher
```

However you can implement the `EventDispatcher` class's `IEventDispatcher` interface and then use an `EventDispatcher` object like the following:

```
internal class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass implements IEventDispatcher
{
    private var _eventDispatcher:EventDispatcher;

    public function ConcreteClass()
    {
        _eventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher(this);

    }// end function

    public function addEventListener(type:String, 
                                     listener:Function, 
                                     useCapture:Boolean = false, 
                                     priority:int = 0, 
                                     useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
    {
        _eventDispatcher.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

    }// end function

    public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean
    {
        return _eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event);

    }// end function

    public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean
    {
        return _eventDispatcher.hasEventListener(type);

    }// end function

    public function removeEventListener(type:String, 
                                        listener:Function, 
                                        useCapture:Boolean = false):void
    {
        _eventDispatcher.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);

    }// end function

    public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean
    {
        return _eventDispatcher.willTrigger(type);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Using this combination of composition and interfaces you can use the concrete class as both an `AbstractClass` and `EventDispatcher` object.

Interfaces are great for allowing "unrelated objects to communicate with one another". You can find more information on interfaces [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html).

Comment: Spelling police has arrived: "Concrete", like the building material.

Comment: i'd just like to add that while you are certainly correct that we can't extend from multiple classes, we can implement multiple interfaces: `public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass implements IEventDispatcher, IAnotherInterface, IWhateverElse`

Comment: I've got a followup question: why wouldn't this work without interfacing? The methods are all the same...

Comment: @alteveer I wiped away all the evidence so the spelling police have got nothing on me :)

Comment: You make a great point on using `implement` to mimic the extension of multiple classes. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that might help you understand a little better.

```
public interface IPlayableItem {
  function playMe():void;
}

public class VideoPlayer implements IPlayableItem {
  public function playMe():void {
    //do video playing stuff here
  }
}


public class AudioPlayer implements IPlayableItem {
  public function playMe():void {
    //do audio playing stuff here
  }
}


public class SlideShowPlayer implements IPlayableItem {
  public function playMe():void {
    //do image slideshow stuff here
  }
}

public class Main {
  public var myPlayables:Array = new Array();

  public function Main() {
    buildMyItems();
    runMyItems();
  }

  public function buildMyItems():void {
    myPlayables.push(new VideoPlayer());
    myPlayables.push(new AudioPlayer());
    myPlayables.push(new SlideShowPlayer());
  }

  public function runMyItems():void {
    for each (var item:IPlayableItem in myPlayables) {
       item.playMe();
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, it doesn't matter how each item needs to implement the code necessary for each to play (each would be notably different in this case). But it provides a common interface for interacting with each one so it's not important to other classes how each class implementing the interface accomplishes what it needs to.

Comment: It would be better to use a Vector.<IPlayableItem> for myPlayables

Comment: Maybe so, but understanding interfaces is the point of my post.

Comment: Thank you for this example!  This has helped the idea of interfaces finally click a bit more in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question I've wondered my self. From discussions with colleagues (who are also concerned with the same topic):

- `Interface`s let your compiler / runtime know what functions are avialable quickly for a potentially nice performance boost depending on the language (and compiler).
- In a *team* environment, an `Interface` can let other devs know which features are needed. Perhaps by name they can easily decipher what the function needs inside it.
- Similar to a column structure in your "standard" databases, an `Interface` will lock you neatly into the same method layout for several classes. This is handy on big projects with hefty *extend*ing and/or *polymorphism* because your compiler will "remind" you if you missed a method implementation.

Also, **Senocular** covers this in [one of his `OOP` artciles](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=5). He is one smart guy when it comes to AS3.

Comment: +1 all good points.  i would be particularly interested to know if and how much of a performance boost there is in AS3 when using interfaces.

Comment: @TheDark - That makes two of us. I would suspect any increase is nominal, but curiosity still demands to know!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like quite a few people have tried explaining the use of interfaces here, but somehow I feel that the real use of interfaces hasn't been captured here. Though this is quite well explained in any Object Oriented Analysis and Design book, I'm putting it in my own words below.

One of the primary uses of Interfaces according to me, is to make a "plugin" architecture possible. What is a plugin? A plugin is a piece of logic that extends the functionality of the base application, without needing the base application to be recompiled. In short, someone defines an interface once, and others who write their code to implement that interface, can plug their new code into the old application, extending it as they choose.

For example, let's take the popular case of Winamp, the music player. The developers of Winamp defined an architecture that allows the creation of plugins to do various things. For example, you might have a plugin that writes out the currently playing MP3 as a wav file. Or a "Virtual Surround" plugin that takes a normal mp3 and makes it sound way better.

Here, the thing to note is that the developer of Winamp might not have imagined that his player could be "extended" to do a particular thing. He would have just defined all the operations that can be done by a plugin. For example, he might have defined an interface IMusicOperation as below

```
public interface IMusicOperation
{
   function Play():void;
   function Pause():void;
   function TrackSeekTo(offset:double):void;  
}
```

When I as a plugin developer implement this interface, it allows me to control Winamp in whatever way I want. For example, I might have a web service that allows someone to control Winamp from a remote location.

Another practical analogy that I find useful is the interface for driving a vehicle in a game.

```
public interface IDriveVehicle
{
  function Start():void;
  function Stop():void;
  function TurnLeft():void;
  function TurnRight():void;
}
```

Now, the great part is that if any vehicle (be it a rocket, spaceship, car, bike, boat, submarine) implements this interface, my gaming code could manipulate this vehicle without needing to know anything more about it. Best part is that even a few years after my game has hit the market, someone could "add" a new spaceship to my game, just by creating a plugin that conforms to my IDriveVehicle interface.

It also allows my application to load components at run-time, which support the interface that I have exposed.

For more information, this looks like a good link... http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/interfaces.html

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this works without interfacing.

I think it is more helpful when you want to push the classes to a vector. You could make a vector like this:

```
var myExampleList:Vector.<IExample> = new Vector.<IExample>();
myExampleList.push(new HungryClass());
myExampleList.push(new FullClass());
```

Answer (score 0):

food analogies are way over used in programming, but i like to think of interfaces as required ingredients for a recipe, so interfaces can be used as a guide for class design.

```
public interface IChocolateChipCookies
{
     function butter(amount:Number):void;
     function sugar(amount:Number):void;
     function eggs(amount:Number):void;
     function vanillaExtract(amount:Number):void;
     function flour(amount:Number):void;
     function water(amount:Number):void;
     function salt(amount:Number):void;
     function walnuts(amount:Number):void;
     function chocolateChips(amount:Number):void;
}
```

then use that interface in your class:

```
public class BakeCookies extends Sprite implements IChocolateChipCookies
{
     public function BakeCookies()
     {

     }

     //must include all functions (ingredients) from IChocolateChipCookies
     //in this class in order to make the cookies correctly!

     private function butter(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function sugar(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function eggs(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function vanillaExtract(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function flour(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function water(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function salt(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function walnuts(amount:Number):void
     {

     }

     private function chocolateChips(amount:Number):void
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Essentially, Interfaces mainly serve purpose in providing a reference to a common function within multiple different classes, that have implemented the specified interface.